# Cannot detect WebVR mode - Insert phone into Cardboard holder

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, expo, aframe

I am trying to run [aframe](https://aframe.io/) "hello world" example on [snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/). When I try going into VR mode (clicking on cardboard icon in bottom right corner) I get message "Insert phone into Cardboard holder".

I can't find a way to get past the message. It seems unable to detect that the phone is placed inside the cardboard holder for some reason. The "Auto Rotate" on my phone is enabled.

When I press the "X" icon it just goes back to standard 3D mode (not split screen).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/hello-world'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**Current Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation turns out the app was locked in portrait mode, so aframe couldn't detect landscape orientation.

As a quick test I tried the following to verify:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class MyWeb extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Expo.ScreenOrientation.allow(Expo.ScreenOrientation.Orientation.LANDSCAPE)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/hello-world'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```